# Accessing shared folders remotely from a local machine

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, network-shares, remote-access

I have a local machine on which I have shared some folders and files.

That local machine is based on Ubuntu 16.

How can I access those shared folders remotely or outside network?

Comment: What software did you use to share these folders?

Comment: I used Ubuntu Samba to share directories